# How do bulk update with EntityManager in JPA/Play based on certain conditions?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

Currently, we're getting a `ResultList` of entities that fit a criteria and then looping through it and setting the same value on each of them one by one. This is very slow. How could we instead do a bulk update using EntityManager?

As an example, I want to set the field `isValid` to `true` for all users that have an SSN and Phone. How would I do this in an efficient/performant way?

Is it like this?

```
final int changes = entityManager.createQuery(
        "update User set isValid = :isValid WHERE SSN IS NOT NULL AND Phone IS NOT NULL")
        .setParameter("isValid", true)
        .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How do you know its slow? What specific benchmarks  and profiling have you done? Where is the code slow at?  What is the data structure of the entity manager? How many entities are you going through? Is there a a database in this? The code you put almost looks like database call names.

Comment: @Underbalanced I know it's slow because when we run it it is very slow. It also makes sense that it's slow as it's doing a query for every single entity in the loop.

Comment: Which JPA provider do you use in your setting?

Comment: @MWiesner Play framework